# Angular mat-navigation - remove blue glow around items per page drop down

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular material navigation-panel. Whenever I select the items per page drop down, a bluish border appears which goes away if I click outside. How to get rid off this border in my own css?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPDTZ.png)

Comment: Remove or replace? I think removing this would be an accessibility issue.

Comment: Yeah, removing could be an accessibility issue. But one empty div with blue border still remain after selection which is not a good look and feel.